# Specify several commands with variable number of args for qmake target

Tags: qt, qmake

in a Qt project using QMake I have a target with a custom command `my_tool` that can take any number of arguments:

```
target.commands = my_tool.exe arg01 arg02  # works fine
```

If I now need to run that command twice ...

```
target.commands = my_tool.exe arg01 arg02
target.commands += my_tool.exe another_arg01 another_arg02  # breaks
```

... for that target, the first command fails because the second command is used as arguments for the first. As in: when I output the arguments of the first command, it says:

```
ARGV[0]: my_tool.exe
ARGV[1]: arg01
ARGV[2]: arg02
ARGV[3]: my_tool.exe
ARGV[4]: another_arg01
ARGV[5]: another_arg02
```

How would I add a second command so that it is treated separately?

Thank you for any help or pointers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1**

One possibility is to simply use two separate targets:

```
target1.commands = my_tool.exe arg01 arg02
target2.commands = my_tool.exe another_arg01 another_arg02
```

... and make one depend on the other:

```
target1.depends = target2
```

**Way 2**

Another way is to specify `$$escape_expand(\n\t)` or `&&` between the commands:

```
target.commands = my_tool.exe arg01 arg02  $$escape_expand(\n\t)  my_tool.exe another_arg01 another_arg02

target.commands = my_tool.exe arg01 arg02  &&  my_tool.exe another_arg01 another_arg02
```

So there's plenty of ways to chosse from. :)